# Postgres Query Logins per User over 30 days counting each day only once

Tags: postgresql, select

I'm writing a query to get the number of logins a user has done in the last 30 days.

The catch is a User can login multiple times per day but I only want to count one entry per day. So the maximum return value for a user would be 30.

I could do this logic in Node but I'm keen to see if it can be done on the query

Below is PID, UserID, DateTime of Login (order by Login) - 'logins table'

```
9   1000000000  2020-12-08 14:01:56
10  1000000000  2020-12-08 14:01:56
8   1000000000  2020-12-09 14:01:56
20  1000000001  2020-12-09 14:04:48
19  1000000001  2020-12-09 14:04:48
18  1000000001  2020-12-09 14:04:48
7   1000000000  2020-12-10 14:01:56
6   1000000000  2020-12-11 14:01:56
16  1000000001  2020-12-11 14:04:48
17  1000000001  2020-12-11 14:04:48
5   1000000000  2020-12-12 14:01:56
24  1000000002  2020-12-12 14:05:46
4   1000000000  2020-12-13 14:01:56
15  1000000001  2020-12-13 14:04:48
14  1000000001  2020-12-13 14:04:48
26  1000000002  2020-12-13 14:05:46
25  1000000002  2020-12-13 14:05:46
3   1000000000  2020-12-14 14:01:56
13  1000000001  2020-12-14 14:04:48
1   1000000000  2020-12-15 14:01:13
2   1000000000  2020-12-15 14:01:56
11  1000000000  2020-12-15 14:01:56
12  1000000001  2020-12-15 14:04:48
21  1000000001  2020-12-15 14:04:48
23  1000000002  2020-12-15 14:05:46
22  1000000002  2020-12-15 14:05:46
```

Query - not sure how to get 1 value for a day with multiple logins. Group by wouldn't work. Maybe there is a Windows Function that accommodates this.

```
select * 
from dating.logins 
where 
    userid = 1000000000
    and datetime > NOW() - INTERVAL '30 DAY'
order by datetime;
```

Comment: I would make the date a string then cut off the day part and group by that ... select count(*), pid from logins group by substr(cast(date,string),0,10) or some such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this :

```
select userid, 
  count(distinct date_trunc('day', datetime)) as  countLogins
from dating.logins 
where 
    userid = 1000000000
    and datetime > NOW() - INTERVAL '30 DAY'
Group by userId;
```

Comment: Brilliant - thanks so much... I switched 'date_trunc' for 'trunc'... cheers!